# Errors on Open-Source Document

Tags: java, android, eclipse, open-source

I downloaded an open-source document called apple-crunch and I imported the document to the project I created.  All of the folders have no error but the java files aren't in the source folder, rather they are in another folder called apple-crunch.  I then created that folder to be a source under the source tab of the java build path.  It then contained errors, when I removed it as a source, the errors disappeared.

How would I get rid of the errors properly while at the same time retain all the data?  The errors were :

- cannot be resolved into a type
- the constructor is undefined
- the method method() is undefined for the type Sprite class.java

Answer (score 0):

Is apple-crunch a jar file? If so, you need to add it to your build path in order for Eclipse to pick it up and include it in your project. The errors you were seeing:

> - cannot be resolved into a type
> - the constructor is undefined
> - the method method() is undefined for the type Sprite class.java

are all indicative of the file not being included on the classpath. To remedy the situation is easy, if it's a classpath error.

1. Create a libs directory in your project in eclipse.
2. Drop the JAR file into the newly created libs directory.
3. Right click on the project name, select build path from the drop down options, and then pick configure build path.
4. Select the libraries tab and choose ADD JAR
5. Navigate to the libs folder from the file picker and choose the apple-crunch jar.
6. Select the order and Export tab and select the apple-crunch jar.
7. Apply the changes and clean your project.

Comment: No, apple-crunch is an opensource project from the command line on google code :  svn checkout http://apple-crunch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: In order to use it in your project you have to build a dependency from it to your source code--even though it's a complete standalone project and not a library. You have a couple of options. Dump the source code in with your code (generally not advised). Create a new eclipse project for the source code and build a dependency relationship from your project. Three, build it as a .jar file and included it in your code as a library.

Comment: For the 2nd option, are you saying that I build a new project from scratch or framwork, using the methods inside the apple-crunch project?  I have a problem with the 3rd option because i intended to change the actual code while still retain some of its important aspects.